# Three raycaster, why do I have to go with index zero?

Tags: three.js

I tried to get the index of the particle I crossed with my mouse cursor while using raycaster.
however,
When I log intersects, it returns a millions of object even if I only came across one point.

I could access to the exact match only when I go with index zero of the intersects array.

And I have to pass the params.points.threshold to get the intersects.For test, I put 0.1 as a experiment. But I don't know the meaning of it quite clearly.

Does anyone know the reason?

My code is as below.

1. Setting raycaster and pass in threshold parameter.

   ```
    const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    raycaster.params.Points.threshold = 0.01;
   ```
2. Shader set up for my geometry

   ```
    const waterGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2, 128, 128)

    // Material
    const waterMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        // wireframe: true,
        vertexShader: waterVertex,
        fragmentShader: waterFragmentShader,
        uniforms: {
        uBigWavesElevation: { value: 0.2 },
        uBigWavesFrequency: { value: new THREE.Vector2(4, 1.5) },
        uTime: { value: 0 },
        uBigWavesSpeed: { value: 0.75 }
    }
    })
   ```
3. set up the size of points comprising my geometry

   ```
    let { count } = waterGeometry.attributes.position

    let scales = new Float32Array(count);

    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        scales[i] = 0.1;
    };
    waterGeometry.setAttribute('scale', new BufferAttribute(scales, 1))
    const water = new THREE.Points(waterGeometry, waterMaterial)
   ```
4. define highlight function

   ```
    function mouseHighlight() {
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera)
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([water]);
    if (intersects[0] != undefined) {

        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (i != scales[intersects[0].index]) {
                scales[i] = 0.1;
            }
        }

        console.log(intersects[0].index);
        scales[intersects[0].index] = 0.5;
        waterGeometry.attributes.scale.needsUpdate = true;


    }

    }
   ```
5. The part I really don't understand

- const intersect is supposed to return intersects only but when I log it, it logs a ton of array.

> const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([water]);

To get the point, I had to choose the first element of the intersects.
It confuses me a lot because for me, intersects mean objects which are intersecting.
So it is not necessary to pick the first element of intersects object.
But I had to. Why?

```
    console.log(intersects[0].index);
    scales[intersects[0].index] = 0.5;
```

- Why do I have to set threshold? and why it always returns slightly off value.

  ```
    const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    raycaster.params.Points.threshold = 0.01;
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Point` has no volume in 3D space, even though it looks like it does when rendered. It is literally a single point in space with no dimensions.

The chances of an interactively-defined ray hitting a single point in space are very VERY small. So, you need a threshold to tell `Raycaster` how "fuzzy" you want the intersections to be against points. According to the docs, this [threshold is in world units](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.params).

Now, based on that, your threshold should be small enough to pick points within the space you have defined, without returning a large number of them. But if that's not working, then I suggest adding a minimal reproducible example to your question, with far fewer points, standard materials, etc.